# How to move any image any time across same layout

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

My requirent is to generate multiple images dynamically and perform all operation on it like drag, drop, scale, rotate.I want every image can move on whole layout. but the problem is in which area 1 image can move another image can not move. I want user can any time select any image and any image can move any where in the layout.

My code to generate Image randomly inside onclick

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams imParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    imge = new ImageView(MultiTouch.this);
    imge.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    imge.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    imge.buildDrawingCache();
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imge.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    imge.setId(i++);

    ll.addView(imge, imParams);
```

My ontouch listnner :

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Toast.makeText(MultiTouch.this, "onTouch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

         boolean defaultResult = v.onTouchEvent(event);



        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:



            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN     " );

            break;


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                System.out.println("ACTION_POINTER_DOWN     " );
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                v.clearFocus();
                System.out.println("ACTION_POINTER_UP     " );
                return false;
    //          break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float tx = values[2];
                        float ty = values[5];
                        float sx = values[0];
                        float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                        float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                        // matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                        matrix.postRotate(r, view.getWidth() / 2,
                                view.getHeight() / 2);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("ACTION_MOVE     " );
                break;
             default:
                  return defaultResult;
            }

            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

and my xml code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frmlayut"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/backgrd"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

can any one tell me How to move any image any time across whole layout? Do i need to make layers, If yes how to do it.